# Optimization problem with if condition as constraint

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, linearization, pyomo

I am trying to solve an optimization problem where the constraint contains absolute values and I am not sure how I can express this in a '[Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org)-friendly' way.

Consider the following optimization problem:

$$\max_{b_{n}} \sum_{n} \space a_{n}(b_{n} - c_{n})$$

subject to $a_{n} > 0$ and $b_{n} = \begin{cases} c_{n}, & |b_{n} - c_{n}|\leq \epsilon \\ b_{n}, & |b_{n} - c_{n}| > \epsilon \end{cases}$.

As this is not a linear constraint, my guess is that this is not solvable. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40873161) question where it is mentioned that there are some modelling tricks.

Comment: Is $a_n>0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Yup, I will edit the post.

Comment: What are the optimization variables?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The $\max_{b_n}$ suggests that the $b_n$ are the variables and everything else is a constant, but my formulation works even if $c_n$ is also a variable.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, indeed, but the "subject to $a_n > 0$" suggests something else. This confusion is avoided when people follow the convention of picking the first letters of the alphabet for knowns and the last letters of the alphabet for unknowns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to enforce the disjunction
$$(b_n - c_n < -\epsilon) \lor (b_n - c_n = 0) \lor (b_n - c_n > \epsilon).$$
You can instead enforce the following disjunction:
$$(b_n - c_n \le -\epsilon) \lor (b_n - c_n = 0) \lor (b_n - c_n \ge \epsilon).$$
Assume finite bounds $L \le b_n - c_n \le U$.  Introduce binary variables $x_n$, $y_n$, and $z_n$, and impose the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_n + y_n + z_n &= 1 &&\text{for all $n$}\\
Lx_n + 0y_n + \epsilon z_n \le b_n - c_n &\le -\epsilon x_n + 0y_n + Uz_n &&\text{for all $n$}\\
\end{align}
Alternatively, omit $y_n$ and instead impose:
\begin{align}
x_n + z_n &\le 1 &&\text{for all $n$}\\
Lx_n + \epsilon z_n \le b_n - c_n &\le -\epsilon x_n + Uz_n &&\text{for all $n$}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for the help! I think I am following but I was wondering if you could briefly explain the difference between the lower bound L and the epsilon mentioned in my post.

Comment: $L<-\epsilon < 0<\epsilon <U$

Comment: Understood! Very cool solution, thanks a lot.